# How to convert Python networkx graph into pygsp

Tags: python, networkx

I was using Python and am attempting to convert a `networkx` graph into `pygsp` graph to plot a signal. However, I cannot understand the documentation on how to do this simple bit of code. I am trying to use the function `from_networkx` listed here: [here](https://pygsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/graphs.html#pygsp.graphs.Graph.from_networkx).

**Attempt:**

I am running the following code within a Google Colab notebook (just some made up example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

# Make the networkx graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add some cars (just do 4 for now)
G.add_nodes_from([
      ('Ford', {'y': 0}),
      ('Lexus', {'y': 1}),
      ('Peugot', {'y': 2}),
      ('Mitsubushi', {'y': 3}),
      ('Mazda', {'y': 4}),
])

# Relabel the nodes
remapping = {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(G.nodes(data = True))}
remapping

G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, remapping, copy=True)
G.nodes(data = True)

# Add some edges --> A = [(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0)] as the adjacency matrix
G.add_edges_from([
                  (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4),
                  (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3),
                  (2, 1), (2, 4), 
                  (3, 0), (3, 1),
                  (4, 0), (4, 2)
])

!pip install pygsp
import pygsp

pygsp_graph = pygsp.graphs.Graph.from_networkx(G)
```

I keep getting errors saying that the module doesn't contain the function `from_networkx`. I have tried different combinations, but for some reason cannot figure out how to do this extremely simple task.

The real network I am using also has some edge weights denoted by 'weight' in the networkx edge list, so those should also be able to be converted via the `weight` argument of the pygsp `from_networkx` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/epfl-lts2/pygsp/issues/58), `from_networkx` and `to_networkx` are only available in the development version which you can install on google colab with `!pip install git+https://github.com/epfl-lts2/pygsp`. Once you do that, the code runs normally.

See code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

# Make the networkx graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add some cars (just do 4 for now)
G.add_nodes_from([
      ('Ford', {'y': 0}),
      ('Lexus', {'y': 1}),
      ('Peugot', {'y': 2}),
      ('Mitsubushi', {'y': 3}),
      ('Mazda', {'y': 4}),
])

# Relabel the nodes
remapping = {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(G.nodes(data = True))}
remapping

G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, remapping, copy=True)
G.nodes(data = True)

# Add some edges --> A = [(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0)] as the adjacency matrix
G.add_edges_from([
                  (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4),
                  (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3),
                  (2, 1), (2, 4), 
                  (3, 0), (3, 1),
                  (4, 0), (4, 2)
])

!pip install git+https://github.com/epfl-lts2/pygsp
import pygsp

pygsp_graph = pygsp.graphs.Graph.from_networkx(G)
print(pygsp_graph)
```

And the output gives:

`Graph(n_vertices=5, n_edges=6)`

Comment: many thanks for the response! You are right, changing that line of the pip install allows the code to work perfectly